# Another word/phrase for something being very "push-button"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

What's another word for something being very "push-button"? What this means is a set of tasks that are made in a way that is very easy and as easy as "pushing a button".

Another phrase is like something being in "pill-form" - something that is easy to do or get.

Sample sentence: "This online advertising service is made in a push-button manner. You just have to fill out a short form, and we'll create and manage the entire advertising campaign for you."

Comment: Please include a sample sentence to demonstrate how the word is to be used.

Comment: @KillingTime "This online advertising service is made in a push-button manner. You just have to fill out a short form, and we'll create and manage the entire advertising campaign for you."

Answer (score 1):

Another word/phrase for something being very “push-button”?

**(as) easy as pie**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/(as)+easy+as+pie) phrase

> extremely easy, simple, or intuitive; requiring very little skill or
>   effort.

Answer (score 1):

The established analogy is to physical keys used as part of an ignition system (such as when starting a car):

> **turnkey** *adjective*
>   Of or involving the provision of a complete product or service that is ready for immediate use.
>   ‘turnkey systems for telecommunications customers’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/turnkey)

Your example would look like this:

- This online advertising service is made in a *turnkey* manner. You just have to fill out a short form, and we'll create and manage the entire advertising campaign for you.

Answer (score 0):

“Drag-and-drop”, “cookie cutter”, “pre-fabricated”, “plug-and-play”, maybe even “lick-and-stick”, which I personally look for excuses to use.

Answer (score 0):

"This online advertising service is made in a [straightforward](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/straightforward) manner."

Cambridge: easy to understand; clear